# How to adapt Android sample soft keyboard to larger screen?

Tags: android, screen, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to deploy the Android Sample Soft Keyboard as provided with the SDK (2.3.3 February 2012), entirely unchanged, to a device with larger screen (HTC Sensation with 960x540 pixels and 240 LCD density, 4.2 inch diameter).

I noticed that the input view occupies half the screen with the keyboard aligned to the top leaving enormous room for black margins (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eim5P.png) below).

I have tried really hard to make the keyboard/input view align to the bottom of the screen and get rid of the black margins - to no avail (editing the `input.xml/qwerty.xml/*.xml` apparently does not help).

I can reproduce the behaviour on a virtual device (emulator) with these settings: 960x540 pixels, 240 LCD density) so I think my real device is not the problem.

Any indication on how this might be achieved is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

[image: Issue]

Answer (score 1):

After two days of searching I have found the solution myself: adding the following line to "AndroidManifest.xml" did the trick:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>
```

As I am a newbie on Android I cannot explain why this works - but it does (both in the emulator and the real device). The black margins have gone and the layout works as specified and desired. Hopefully this is useful for others.